# State isn't show in shipping to address in cart page and selected state in are not checked in checkout page or display order received / thank you page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Due to base country and billing or shipping country are same, country aren't show in cart page shipping to area and order received / thank you page, then I apply this filter to show country.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_formatted_address_force_country_display', '__return_true' );
```

and now country is visible but how to display state like that.

[image]

And the other problem I selected "**Burstadt**" as a state here but in checkout page Billing address always selected in "**Lampertheim**" but shipping address are selected the right state.

[image]

Because of these two problems order received / thank you page aren't also display the state area. How to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your base country is Germany(guessing from the images), the default behaviour for the formatted addresses is to not show state. If you want to change that check the hook `woocommerce_localisation_address_formats` and return `"{company}\n{name}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{city} {postcode}\n{state}, {country}"` for `DE`. See further details [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-countries.html#source-view.507)

I believe this should solve it for all the cases you have.

As for why your billing address state isn't showing correctly. You probably are a logged in user and probably used that state previously so it is saved into your account/profile. You can change that information directly from your account.

Comment: Its true, default behavior for the formatted addresses is to not show state because my base country is Germany. That's why I push some state based on German.

Comment: So if you add a filter hook to change the default format, you should be able to achieve what you want. Let me know if that solved it for you.

Comment: Is it any way to forcefully selected billing address state which state I selected in our cart page?

Comment: I am not sure about that part really. I doubt it though

Comment: It's not a big deal, you help me a lot. Thank you Shivaramanaiyer.

Comment: Happy to help. :)